# Confused with Enum and bitwise operations

Tags: c#, enums, bitwise-operators, flags

If I want to check a combined value with enum value, I run following code (included there remarks)

```
    // 001 | 010 = 011.
    Enum1 firstAndSecond1 = Enum1.First | Enum1.Second;                                    
    // 011 | 000 = 011 == true but should be false!
    Console.WriteLine("None: {0}", (firstAndSecond1 | Enum1.None) == firstAndSecond1);
    
    // 0010 | 0100 = 0110.
    Enum2 firstAndSecond2 = Enum2.First | Enum2.Second;                                    
    // 0110 | 0001 = 0111 == false.
    Console.WriteLine("None: {0}", (firstAndSecond2 | Enum2.None) == firstAndSecond2);   
    
    public enum Enum1
    {
        None   = 0b_000,
        First  = 0b_001,
        Second = 0b_010,
        Third  = 0b_100,
        All    = 0b_111
    }
    public enum Enum2
    {
        None   = 0b_0001,
        First  = 0b_0010,
        Second = 0b_0100,
        Third  = 0b_1000,
        All    = 0b_1111
    }
```

The problem is if I assign `None`value as `0`, the check is incorrect as it returns `true`, it only works if `None`value is set as `1 << 0`

Should the None value always be set as power of two or am I missing something? Because, for example, looking at this topic: [What does the [Flags] Enum Attribute mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8447/what-does-the-flags-enum-attribute-mean-in-c), all `None` values start from `0`in all examples - this is what is confusing me

Comment: Your enums are not Flags enums

Comment: A flags enum represents a number of different possibilities, more than one of which might be set at a time. So your enum can have the `First` flag set or cleared, and also independently have the `Second` flag set of cleared.

`None` means that no flags are at all. You can't have an enum which has the `First` flag set, and also has no flag set (i.e. is `None`).

You seem to be expecting `None` to behave the same as one of the other flags, so an enum can be both `None` **and** `First`. I think that's where the confusion is coming from.

Comment: So, `None` should have the value `0`, because a value of `0` means that none of the bits are set (because if any bit was set, the value would be non-zero)

Comment: (and by this token asking whether the enum has the bits `firstAndSecond2 | Enum2.None` set is a meaningless question, because an enum can't have both the `First` and `Second` bits set, **and also** have no bits set)